# How do I disable babel minification when not in production?

Tags: babeljs, minify, babelify

I am using `babelify` and `babili` for JS minification, via gulp:

```
// Now run the watchifys function for this bundle
watchifysForBundle[jsBundle]
    // Note: we don't use any babel presets - instead we just write code in what evergreen browsers support
    .transform(babelify, {
        presets: ['babel-preset-babili'],
        ignore: ['buffer']
    })
```

However I can't seem to find how to pass the options to check NODE_ENV and disable `babeli` when not in production. The [babelify docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babelify) don't seem to help, even with this common use case.

**How can I disable babelify minification when not in production?**

Answer (score 2):

*Babili is deprecated and has been renamed to [`babel-minify`](https://github.com/babel/minify), so you should be using that instead.*

```
npm install babel-preset-minify --save-dev
```

To disable the minification in development you simply don't use the `babel-preset-minify` (or `babel-preset-babili` for that matter). As you're using Gulp you can use everything Node.js has to offer to decide which presets you want to include, which means that you can check `process.env.NODE_ENV` and decide whether you want to include the `minify` preset.

```
watchifysForBundle[jsBundle]
    .transform(babelify, {
        presets: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? ['minify'] : [],
        ignore: ['buffer']
    })
```

An alternative would be to use [Babel's `env` option](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc#env-option) (not to confuse with [`babel-preset-env`](https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env)), which uses the configuration that matches the value of `BABEL_ENV` or `NODE_ENV` if no `BABEL_ENV` was defined. This approach is shown in [`babel-preset-minify` - Usage](https://github.com/babel/minify#usage-1).

```
{
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "presets": ["minify"]
    }
  }
}
```

The `env` option is not really recommended and mainly exists because `.babelrc` is JSON and there is no good way to define conditional configurations. This will change in Babel 7 which allows a `.babelrc.js` config where you have the full power of Node.js and that means you could do the same thing as with Gulp.

Comment: Thankyou! The rename also explains why I was having so much trouble finding documentation!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid minification, don't use uglify

```
gulp.task('build:js', function(){
    return browserify(
         'test.js'
    )
    .transform('babelify',{
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
    })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('test.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('destpath'));
});
```

Instead try---  adding option- compact:false, global:true in babelify

```
gulp.task('build:js', function(){
    return browserify(
         'test.js'
    )
    .transform('babelify',{
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
      compact: false,
      global: true
    })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('test.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('destpath'));
});
```